# Is there a Google Trips API?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Google has a Trips product: https://get.google.com/trips/ ([Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.travel.onthego))

**Is there an API for it?** I'd like to get day by day travel guides for cities. I found search for flight trips ([here](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search)), but that is not what I want.

With furtherer Googling, I was able to find [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), but this seems to be a navigation API, not Trips.

Thank you

Comment: Qpx express api is flight information not exactly sure what your definition of trips is

Comment: @DaImTo Take a look at the app I've linked.

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve. Trips could mean a lot of things

Comment: @DaImTo Sure. The Google Trips app has a itinerary planer, as in, on day one go visit XXX tourist attractions, on day two visit XXX tourist attractions, and so forth. That's what I want to implement.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Did You able to do it? Will You please tell me how did you do it? Would You please post some specs of code for the same Please ?

Comment: @Sourav I never found it.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac  then How did You solve the issue? I mean how to create an itinerary app like Google Trips. Can You please guide ?

Comment: I've never solved it